# Find last value in a row

Tags: google-sheets

After searching for a while on the site, I could find a lot of people asking about finding the last row in a column, but I'm looking for the opposite, so when I tried to reverse their solutions using the appropriate functions I couldn't get it to work.

I have searched the google spreadsheet help pages for a solution as well and as such I've tried with `COUNT()`, `COUNTA()`,`MATCH()`, `ROW()`, `COLUMN()`, `LOOKUP()`, `VLOOKUP()`, `HLOOKUP` and `INDEX()` or any combination of those to find my solution.

The closest solution I could find is `=LOOKUP(N61,PR!A:A,PR!H:H)` or using the search array of `PR!A1:IF1000`. But the information is not sorted so it wouldn't work.

So what I want to do is I have 2 sheets. 1 with information on it, and a second with a search function.

The first one has information on a expanding column and expanding rows with the most up to date information being on the last column of the row (with a value).

The second one basically says, what are you searching for from a drop down menu of the A column of the 1st sheet, and then on the next line it will give you the most up to date information.

Thanks in advance!

Example:

Sheet 1:

[image: Sheet 1]

Sheet Two:

[image: Sheet 2]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Hi Joe. I have added an example.

Comment: 2. "Have you explained what you've already tried to solve your problem?"

Comment: Well, I've come up with something that works but it doesn't look pretty. The item to be searched is in cell `B50`. Here's the function: `=filter(INDIRECT(MATCH(B50,A:A,0)&":"&MATCH(B50,A:A,0)),column(INDIRECT(MATCH(B50,A:A,0)&":"&MATCH(B50,A:A,0)))=max(if(INDIRECT(MATCH(B50,A:A,0)&":"&MATCH(B50,A:A,0))<>"",column(INDIRECT(MATCH(B50,A:A,0)&":"&MATCH(B50,A:A,0))))))`. So I can't use that on a different sheet obviously and it looks terrible, works, but looks terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your new data will always have a header, you could try this. COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1) will change the vlookup index to the last column with a header. Also, adjust the lookup range as needed

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A1:Z,COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That works perfectly! And now I also understand `COUNTA()` a bit better too. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution based on string manipularion, suitable for numeric data as in your example. The sheet (Sheet7 in my case) is filtered by the column A matching the value in A2 of the present sheet. The result is joined into a pipe-delimited string, and `regexextract` extracts the last nonempty value from it. Since the extracted value is a text, `value` is applied to convert it to numeric.

```
=value(regexextract(join("|", filter(Sheet7!1:1000, Sheet7!A1:A1000 = A2)), "([^|]*)\|*$"))
```

This formula makes no assumption on the number of columns in Sheet7, but expects that there are at most 1000 rows in it.